# Edit only one line in json file with php

Tags: php, json

Hello i Have this json file called votes.json

i want to make vote system using only php and json file to store data

this is json file

```
{
    "main": {
       
            "choice1": "0",
            "choice2": "0",
            "choice3": "0"
       
       
    },
    "alternative": {
       
            "choice1": "0",
            "choice2": "0",
            "choice3": "0"
   
   
}
}
```

i want a php function so for example i edit choice1 in the main

i want to increase the counter every time someone vote for this

so ['main'][choice1] = 1
and next time some one choose the same option become
['main'][choice1] = 2 and keep the others as the same

i tried this code but didn't work as i need

```
$data = file_get_contents('votes.json');

$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($json_arr as $key => $value) {
   
        
        $json_arr['main']['choice1'] = $value+1;


  
}
file_put_contents('results_new.json', json_encode($value));
```

Comment: Please define "did not work as I need". What happens?

Comment: it delete the hole json file and only show the line edited without keeping the others

Comment: Why are you trying to _loop_ over this? $value will be the sub-arrays - and trying to "add 1" to an array makes no sense.

Comment: A quick look at your code shows that you are only encoding a variable and not your full JSON array. Maybe that's where the problem lies...?

Comment: `json_encode($value)` - You're just encoding and storing the last `$value`  from your iteration (which you also never do anything with). You should encode and store the full array. But as others have pointed out, your code has many other problems (like iterating through an array just to set the same specific key on each iteration). There's no need to iterate anything. You should also get and put the same file, or you will keep loosing all previous votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you don't need a loop to increment a specific value. And you have to encode your entire array.

```
$data = file_get_contents('votes.json');

$json_arr = json_decode($data, true);

// Just Increase Choice1 (no need a loop for this)
$json_arr['main']['choice1']++;

// Encode All JSon Array
file_put_contents('results_new.json', json_encode($json_arr));
```

Comment: This still have the problem of loading the array from one file and storing it in another, which will overwrite any previous votes.

Comment: I just took his code to show where the problems were. But if we re-write in the same file, that won't be a problem, right...? Except of course that the file can be read and written simultaneously by several users.